# How to hide certain tags from the_tags()?

Tags: tags

I need to assign some tags to my posts (for external use), but I don't want them showing anywhere that tags are listed. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is not to do this. Use a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I echo @toscho's suggestion. You can setup a taxonomy via your functions.php (use the reference he gave you) file or by using a plugin like [Ultimate Taxonomy Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-taxonomy-manager/).

A custom taxonomy will let you organize your posts as you'd like, without worry about interference with the standard post tags.